# react native camera, onBarCodeRead not working

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-camera

react native camera, onBarCodeRead not working, i have installed react-native-camera, the code trigger the cammera, but it doesnot read or spot barcode even with onBarCodeRead function. 
The below is my code and screenshoot

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { Image, Platform } from 'react-native';
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';
 import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
 import { Container, Header, Title, Content, Button, Icon, List, ListItem, Text, Footer, Left, Right, Body } from 'native-base';

 import styles from './styles';
 import { UserLogin, username,password} from '../../actions/index.js';
 import Spinner from 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay';
 import Camera from 'react-native-camera';
 const glow2 = require('../../../images/glow2.png');

 const backgroundImage = require('../../../images/glow2.png');
 const logo = require('../../../images/logo.png');
 class Qrcamera extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
     <Container style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
       <Image source={glow2} style={styles.container} >

      <Header style={{ backgroundColor: '#004774' }} >
        <Left>
          <Button transparent onPress={this.props.openDrawer} >
            <Icon active name="menu" style={{ fontSize: 30, lineHeight: 32 }} />
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Title>Scanner</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right />

      </Header>

      <Content padder style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>

        <Camera
      ref={(cam) => {
        this.camera = cam;
      }}
      style={styles.preview}
      aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
      onBarCodeRead={this._bacr()}
      barCodeTypes={['org.iso.QRCode']}
      >

    </Camera>


      </Content>


    </Image>
    </Container>
  );
}
 _bacr(){
    alert("hey sported barcode!");
 }

}

export default connect()(Qrcamera);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Uig.png)

Answer (score 1):

Translation

Isn't that you just declared your barCodeTypes wrong?
Mine is like this for reading QR-Code:

```
barCodeTypes={[Camera.constants.BarCodeType.qr]}
```

and it works just fine. Change your barCodeTypes into this and try it again and just make sure that change this:

```
onBarCodeRead={this._bacr()}
```

into this:

```
onBarCodeRead={this._bacr.bind(this)}
```

or:

```
onBarCodeRead={()=>{this._bacr()}}
```

otherwise, when your camera reads a QRcode it won't fire up the function.